# C++ передача возвращаемого значение лямбды в функцию

Tags: c++, функции, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Есть функция, которая просто выводит числа из вектора.

```
void test(std::vector<int> vec)
{
    for(int item: vec)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

Есть вектор:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};
```

Хочу передать в функцию копию этого вектора, у которого все элементы будут больше на 1. 
Сделал это так:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> temp;
    for(int item: vec)
        vec.push_back(item + 1);
    test(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Пока проблем нет, но как пытаюсь сделать через лябмду:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};
    test([vec]() {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        for(int item: vec)
            temp.push_back(item + 1);
        return temp;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Ловлю ошибку:

> could not convert ‘main()::{std::vector(vec)}’ from
>   ‘main()::’ to ‘std::vector

Я понимаю, что в качестве аргумента передается сама лямбда, а как передать то, что она возвращает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же должны передавать не саму лямбду, а *результат ее вызова*!...

```
        return temp;
    }());
    return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание на `()` по завершении лямбды...

Но мне больше нравится вариант передачи вектора, а не его захвата.

```
test([](const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    for(int item: vec)
        temp.push_back(item + 1);
    return temp;
}(vec));
```

А еще больше - вообще без лишнего вектора:

```
void test(std::vector<int>& vec, std::function<int(int)> f)
{
    for(int item: vec)
        std::cout << f(item) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};

    test(vec,[](int i) { return i+1; });
    return 0;
}
```

Никаких промежуточных векторов... Да и в `test` передается ссылка, а не копия из-за передачи по значению :)